# Flex mobile app not working on android 2.2

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air, flash-builder

I have developed an android application using FB 4.6, AIR 3.2.  We wanted to develop this app very quickly, and be able to support wide spectrum of devices incl android, ios, bb.  So I chose FB.  After I uploaded the app in google play, the app says it works on android versions 2.2 on wards.  However when users with android 2.2 devices try to install, it says it is not compatible.

I am confused & curious to know the reasons behind this behavior.  Any help / pointers in this regard is highly appreciated.  Thank you :-)

Comment: Strange behavior... do you use the bundled AIR or the user needs air installed on device ? Android 2.2 should support AIR 2.6 and up...

Comment: I guess you do not have a device running android 2.2 to test... but how about using an android 2.2 sdk simulator ?

Comment: Right now we are not bundling AIR, however we plan to bundle it using captive-runtime.  To answer Adrian, I did not try to run on emulator.  Perhaps I will try that, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I tried installing on android 2.2 simulator, and I get the following error. `code`D:\usrbin\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb install -r c:\Users\admin\Desktop\App-captive-runtime.apk
77 KB/s (11489723 bytes in 145.507s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/App-captive-runtime.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK] `code`

Comment: How do we resolve this issue so that the app can be installed on android 2.2 devices as well.

Comment: when building are you using:  -target apk-emulator  or  -target apk ?

Comment: also please check the following 2 links: http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html  http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flashruntimes/certified-devices.html

Comment: If I remember correctly, AIR does not support all of Android 2.2 releases. It began with one of the incremental updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe Air 3 runs only on Android phones that meet specific hardware requirements:

- ARMv7 processor with vector FPU, minimum 550MHz, OpenGL ES 2.0, H.264 and AAC HW decoders
- 256MB of RAM

An android phone that falls short of these specs will not be compatible with Adobe Air 3, even if it run on Android 2.2 or higher.

[Adobe air tech specs](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html#mobile)

[Discussion on Adobe Community](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/885831)